# why getting null refence exception when giving iconuri in application bar?

Tags: windows-phone-7

in application bar firstly i given some images.when click on that icon need to assign new image.for that in click event wrote the bellow code.

```
 private void searchbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            searchbtn.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/settings_high.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        }
```

Getting NULL Refernce exception.please help me

Comment: Did you set the image as resource

Comment: yes. i set the image as Resource....Getting NULL Refernce exception

Answer (score 2):

In case you did not know (I didn't) you must set the image Build Action property to Content, not resource. Then you can access the file like this:

```
StreamResourceInfo resourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new System.Uri("ima1.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the stack trace shows a `NullReferenceException` *directly* in your method, that suggests that `searchbtn` is null.

I suggest you put a breakpoint on that line of code and run it in the debugger, then use the Auto window to check the value of `searchbtn`.

Is it possible that you've declared your own `searchbtn` variable while there's another *similarly-named* variable which actually has a reference to a button? The event handler name would suggest otherwise, but it's at least worth checking.

If the stack trace shows a `NullReferenceException` *deeper* in the code, that suggests there's a different problem. If you could post the full stack trace, that would help.